# Not able to import python package jax in Google TPU

Tags: python-3.x, tpu, jax, spacy-transformers, sentence-transformers

I am working on linux console and typing python takes me into the python console.
When I use the following command in TPU machine

```python
import jax
```

then it generates following mss and get out of the python prompt.

```bash
paramjeetsingh80@t1v-n-1c883486-w-0:~$ python3
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jan 27 2021, 15:41:15)
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import jax
2021-07-08 17:41:39.660523: F external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/tpu/tpu_executor_init_fns.inc:110] TpuTransferManager_ReadDynamicShapes not available in this library.
Aborted (core dumped)
paramjeetsingh80@t1v-n-1c883486-w-0:~$
```

This issue is causing problem in my code so I would like to figure out, what is this issue and how to get rid of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be that your system does not have the correct version of libtpu. Try installing the version listed [here](https://github.com/google/jax/blob/38884b02f72950a8d187f81420a270e46afe8889/setup.py#L27).

You should be able to do this automatically with

```
$ pip install -U pip  # older pip may not support extra requirements
$ pip install -U jax  # newer jax required for [tpu] extras declaration
$ pip install jax[tpu] -f https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/jax_releases.html
```

Comment: `libtpu` version changes over time. As you update your jax, pytorch/xla, etc. you want check `libtpu` version remains aligned.

Answer (score 1):

Above command give some error but I researched and below command worked for me. But your answer give me the direction that it is a package issue.

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install "jax[tpu]>=0.2.16" -f https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/libtpu_releases.html
```

Comment: this should probably be a comment to the other answer